How to set alpha by bivariate density and fill by z in geom_raster?
I make a heatplot with geom_raster, something like this:
mround <- function(x,base){base*round(x/base)} # round to nearest 5
df <- data.frame(x= mround(rnorm(10000, 100, 10), 5),
                 y= mround(rnorm(10000, 100, 10), 5))
df$z <- df$x + df$y
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_raster(aes(x= x, y= y, fill= z)) +
  theme_classic()


I would like to set the alpha argument for the raster and it should depent on the bivariate density. We can visualize the bivariate density for raster like this:
ggplot() +
  stat_density_2d(data= df, aes(x= x, y= y, alpha = after_stat(density)), geom = "raster", contour= FALSE)


Basically, I want the first plot to have the alpha of the second. I tried all kind of thing, like geom_raster(aes(x= x, y= y, fill= z, alpha = after_stat(density))), but nothing works so far. How can I set the fill by z and alpha by 2d density at the same time?

I think this code cannot be executed. Looks faulty. You are missing library calls. Where is mround from?

@Friede Edited.

This is difficult, because in order to calculate density, ggplot will have to aggregate your data, which loses the value of variables other than x and y at each unique point.
One option is to just precalculate density, which will work if z is indeed just a simple function of x and y:
ranges <- c(min(df$x, df$y), max(df$x, df$y))

n <- 1 + diff(ranges)/5

dens <- MASS::kde2d(df$x, df$y, n = n, lims = c(ranges, ranges))

cbind(expand.grid(x = dens$x, y = dens$y), 
      dens = c(dens$z), z = dens$x + dens$y) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z, alpha = dens)) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 1)) +
  coord_equal()


If, in your actual data, z is an independent variable, then you may need to interpolate its value using something like interp::interp:
cbind(expand.grid(x = dens$x, y = dens$y), 
      dens = c(dens$z), 
      z = c(interp::interp(x = df$x, y = df$y, z = df$z, 
                           duplicate = "mean", xo = dens$x, yo = dens$y)$z)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z, alpha = dens)) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 1)) +
  coord_equal()

Which will give the same output in this particular instance.

Awesome! Two questions: Why did you specify ranges <- c(min(df$x, df$y), max(df$x, df$y))? For my actual data, where x and y have quite different ranges, that made no sense, so I stick to functions default. Why did you change the default bevavior? And: Why is it n <- 1 + diff(ranges)/5?

These were simply to make the bins square and distributed evenly on a grid every 5 units, the same as the data. It works well for the sample data, but maybe not for your  actual data.
